# Modules memberof.la and syncprov.la missing

Tags: openldap

I´ve install a openLDAP on a debian box. To use back-sql I need to compile it from scratch. I also enable modules memberof and syncprov.

./configure --enable-sql --enable-memberof --enable-memberof

Compile works fine and after install openLDAP is running but both modules memberof.la and syncprov.la are not available on the system.

The compiler logs are OK. What could happen??

Comment: Are syncprov.so and memberof.so available? If present, those should be sufficient.